# determine if sample size is sufficient by comparing 25% and median values

Tags: statistical-significance, estimation, sample-size

Currently I have data (true population size is unknown).
There are `n` data points in descending order, and we know the values of `25%` and `50%` percentile, say `x1` and `x2`. How can I estimate if the sample size is sufficient such that x1, x2 are within `5% of margin of errors` of `x1` and `x2`?

For example, suppose `n=1000` and `data={4500, 621, 500,....0.001}`, and the 250-th, 500-th observations are `x1=200` and `x2=50`. How can I know if `n=1000` is big enough such that even if increasing `n`, `x1=200 +/- 10` and `x2=50 +/- 2.5`?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks. I re-edit the question and wish now it is more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to put a confidence interval around an entire empirical CDF using the Dvoretzky-Kiefer-Wolfowitz inequality.

For a sample of size $n$ the empirical CDF will be within $\varepsilon$ of the true CDF with a confidence level of $1- \alpha, $ where

$$\varepsilon =\sqrt{\left( \frac{1}{2n} \right) \ln \left( \frac{2}{\alpha} \right)} $$

For $n=1000$ and a confidence level of 95% ( $\alpha = 0.05$), $\varepsilon \approx 0.0429$

Using this you can draw the confidence bounds on your empirical CDF and put confidence intervals on your estimated percentiles.

Comment: This is a good answer, and very helpful. However, I see a potential problem. If we are plotting $\hat F$, these bounds are "vertical". The confidence bounds on the quantiles however would go "horizontally". But the DKW inequality doesn't depend on $x$, hence for percentiles close to 1 (say $p=.99$) we can never get an upper bound on the quantile using this approach. Am I making any sense? Do you have any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: There are at least two other approaches. There is a binomial-based distribution-free interval. It uses order statistics. Or you could use a resampling approach. Both of these should avoid the bounding problem you mention for extreme percentile estimation.